# Easter Lily Cactus With Orange Spots?

Tags: plant-health, pests, succulents, cactus

I've had this easter lily cactus for about 5-6 years and it's doing good and even produced baby cactuses that I propagated but its got these orange spots on one side of it and not the other and it's had these for a while. When I repotted it I cut some dead roots but almost all the roots where bright yellow-beige but could these orange spots effect the cactus or is it normal? Though it did have a few strings on it when I repotted it which could be spider mites but I took them off (but the other side of the cactus is purely green and looks fine?) i keep it right next to my window which gets quite a lot of sun a day

[image]

Comment: White fuzz looks like mealy bugs. Spray with alcohol and soap. They will suck the life out of that fat mama.